# Turn on auto hide for taskbar on second screen but not on primary screen in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I have a laptop running Windows 8, and recently purchased a monitor to use while at home. I love that there is now a taskbar on both screens, but I wish I could turn on the auto hide feature for the second screen only. I want to have fuller windows on that screen, but still have access to the taskbar. However I do not see an option to use this feature on only one screen, it is either both or neither.

Is there a setting somewhere for this? Or any kind of software that will  let me do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can set this in Windows 8 without a 3rd party taskbar manager.

I use [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/Features/Taskbar/) for my multi-monitor needs.  It has a feature for adding taskbars to extra monitors in all versions of Windows, and the Taskbar Auto-Hide feature can be set per-monitor.

Perhaps give it a try.

Note: I don't work for them or anything; just a happy user. :)

Comment: 8 years late, but is there a free alternative for this? Thanks.

Comment: It's time to get ignored on Feedback Hub again I guess. See you guys there

Answer (score 8):

Just open task bar properties (right click on it, and select properties). So, you can disable the option "show taskbar on all displays", that will display taskbar only on the primary monitor.

[image]

Comment: My eyes .... This is not what the OP is asking for. He wants the second monitor to have the tasbar but not auto-hide. So taskbars on both monitors but auto-hide for primary monitor only.